# Acer laptop running ubuntu, keys not working properly

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, keyboard

I've been working on an Acer Laptop for the last week, today the keyboard has started behaving oddly, specifically when I hold down the shift key and press any of the arrow keys I cannot select text.

Copy, Cut and Paste no longer function correctly.

I've tried rebooting the system and shutting down completely, it comes back in the same state.

I'm running Ubuntu on this laptop, its version 14.04, I don't have any choice on the OS or the version its required for the job I'm working on.

[Edit]  The problem seems isolated to the software package I'm using which is Qt Creator, version 3.0.1

What is the problem?

Comment: Does it work in Qt Creator 3.0.1 on any other hardware?

Comment: Just found the problem, in the Qt Creator Edit menu there is an Advanced Option "Use Vim-style Editing", some how this had got checked, unchecking now its ok.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, in Qt Creator, Edit menu -> "Advanced" there is a checkable option called "Use Vim-style Editing", uncheck this and its back to normal.